# How can I pass from a single element to a list of element in python?

Tags: python, list

I am reading a file with the following code:

```
f = open("Game.txt", "r")
for el in f:
    print(el)
```

The output is the following or similar

```
[[['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'], ['X', '_', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_', '_', '_'], ['X', '_', '_', 'X', 'O', '_', '_', '_', 'O'], ['X', '_', '_', 'X', 'O', '_', 'X', '_', 'O']], [['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'], ['X', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'], ['X', 'X', '_', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', '_', '_', 'O', '_', '_']]]
```

where I have a list of tensor.
I am trying to create a txt file where I have on each line a tensor displayed but I cant because it appears as a single element

I tried to split the tensor so to produce more then one element but is not happening:

```
for el in f:
    print(el.split())
```

Output aspected
[['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['X', '*', '*', '*', 'O', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['X', '*', '*', 'X', 'O', '*', '*', '*', 'O'], ['X', '*', '*', 'X', 'O', '*', 'X', '*', 'O']] \n
[['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['X', '*', '*', 'O', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['X', 'X', '*', 'O', '*', '*', 'O', '*', '*'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', '*', '*', 'O', '*', '*']]

Comment: If you have some kind of data structure you want to save, you shouldn't save it as simple unstructured text. Use JSON for example.

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question.

Comment: @Timus Added the \n must be read in python lenguage

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to write each line (tensor) for each line in a txt file, so you can print it line by line. Thinking it can be a list of elements. Check this example:

```
f = open("demofile3.txt", "w")
while( condition ):
    f.write("Woops! I have deleted the content!")
f.close()
```